What did Moshe do to bring back the Ananei Hakovod?
The Gemara Taanis (9a) says that Moshe Rabbeinu brought back the Ananei Hakovod after Aharon died.

חָזְרוּ שְׁנֵיהֶם בִּזְכוּת מֹשֶׁה, מֵת מֹשֶׁה נִסְתַּלְּקוּ כּוּלָּן,
שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״וָאַכְחִד אֶת שְׁלֹשֶׁת הָרֹעִים בְּיֶרַח אֶחָד״, וְכִי
בְּיֶרַח אֶחָד מֵתוּ? וַהֲלֹא מִרְיָם מֵתָה בְּנִיסָן, וְאַהֲרֹן
בְּאָב, וּמֹשֶׁה בַּאֲדָר! אֶלָּא, מְלַמֵּד שֶׁנִּתְבַּטְּלוּ שָׁלֹשׁ
מַתָּנוֹת טוֹבוֹת שֶׁנִּתְּנוּ עַל יָדָן, וְנִסְתַּלְּקוּ כּוּלָּן
בְּיֶרַח אֶחָד - Both the well and the clouds
of glory returned in the merit of Moses. However, when Moses died all
of them disappeared. As it is stated: “And I cut off the three
shepherds in one month” (Zechariah 11:8). But did the three shepherds
really die in one month? Didn’t Miriam die in the month of Nisan, and
Aaron in Av and Moses in Adar? Rather, this verse teaches us that with
the death of Moses the three good gifts that were given through their
agency were annulled, and all three gifts disappeared in one month,
which made it seem as though all three leaders had died at the same
time.

What special zechus did Moshe do to bring back the protective clouds?
